# Make an Angular *ngFor draw two different columns of data

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to make a *ngFor directive to put data in two columns, instead of just one column as usual. I even followed an example I saw over there, but it didn't work at all. Let's start with the graphic part:

I've got this:
[image]

... but I want it to look like this (so I can fit more items than before without making the card bigger):
[image]

This is the code I currently have, which does absolutely nothing (it just shows the first image):

```
<div class="col-6-md" *ngFor="let level of config?.selectedLevels; let i = index">
      <div class="col-md-6" class="left-style" *ngIf="i%2 == 0">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" [style.cursor]="cursor(level)"  class="btn-flat white separator" (click)="deselectLevel(level)">
              <i class="fa fa-times">
              </i> 
              {{ level?.label || level }}
            </a>          
      </div>  
      <div class="col-md-6" class="right-style" *ngIf="i%2 != 0">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" [style.cursor]="cursor(level)"  class="btn-flat white separator" (click)="deselectLevel(level)">
              <i class="fa fa-times">
              </i> 
              {{ level?.label || level }}
            </a>           
      </div>  
</div>
```

This uses the following CSS:

```
.left-style{
    float:left;
    width:45%;
}
.right-style{
    float:right;
    width:45%;
}
```

I know it wouldn't be needed in this example, but it was just a try. I'm quite confused why this is not working at all. Inside the created divs, the bootstrap classes (col-md-6) are not being applied at all.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

Let me expand a little how the app looks like so it's easy to find out what's going on. After trying other methods that didn't really work, I guess it's time to give you a wider view of what this looks like in order to find out how to fix this weird thing.

The parent component uses "cards" like the one you see upper in this post. So, the main template looks like this:

[image]

The "cards" component has a ng-content which draws inside another component that I provide, as you could see in the parent component's implementation. This is the cards component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: "card",
    styleUrls: ["./card.css"],
    template: `
    <div class="col card">
      <div class="row card-header">
        {{title}}
      </div>
      <div class="margin">
      <ng-content></ng-content>

    </div>
    `
})

export class Card{

    @Input() title: string;

    constructor(){

    }

}
```

Somehow, just as I stated in the comments of the first proposed answer, the divs aren't compiling the bootstrap classes as they normally would:

[image]

It's becoming really weird at this moment. Can anyone spot what's wrong here?

Comment: I was just editing the wrong file all this time. Just monday things. Sorry for stealing your time!

Comment: What if we need to create three column in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have two `class` attributes for each div, so Angular is taking the later class only.

Simply merge the class attribute like:

`<div class="left-style col-md-6" *ngIf="i%2 == 0">`

And both classes will be applied.

You can actually use less html and use `ngClass` as follows

```
 <div class="col-md-6" [ngClass]="{'left-style': i%2 != 0, 'right-style': i%2 === 0 }">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" [style.cursor]="cursor(level)"  class="btn-flat white separator" (click)="deselectLevel(level)">
          <i class="fa fa-times">
          </i> 
          {{ level?.label || level }}
        </a>           
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, though none of the solutions are working. It's still drawing all the list in juts one column :/

Comment: Does it apply the classes?

Comment: Nope. The created divs look like this: "<div _ngcontent-c7="">"

Comment: hmm, I highly doubt that. Can you create a plunkr? or put your code on GIT?

Comment: I can't since it's business code. But I will expand the post, okay? So it's easier to understand what's going on

Comment: What is inside the minimized html in the output?

Comment: What do you mean? By the way, I'm starting to think this has something to do with the ng-content directive of the card component...

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:
I am making the `Angular` demo `Tour of Heroes` and i wanted to divide in two columns the dashboard data *ngFor display;(like this)
[image: by ngFor]

this is code it works for me right now:

```
<!--repeater creates as many links as
          are in the component's heroes array.-->
    <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes;" routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">       
      <!--ESTE STYLE SIRVE PARA QUE NO SE DEMADRE EL TAMAÑO DE CADA
      DIV, ELLIPSIS AYUDA EN ESTO-->
      <div style="
       width: 50%;
       float: left;
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;"
       class="module hero">
          {{hero.name}}            
      </div>         
    </a>
```